# surface 3 and 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boot, surface

i am currently trying to get ubuntu on my surface 3 (not the pro the base model) i have followed at least 3 or 4 different how to guides and nothing seems to be working.
i have tried with and without secure boot i have tried with rufus and unetbootin and i have tried with both 14.04 and 15.10 but whenever i goto to try live boot or even just straight to install it will show the ubuntu loading screen then it just goes to a black screen. Am i doing something wrong? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: when I was using microsoft, I used to use http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Surface + Ubuntu = Nightmare

But there are working solutions. I would recommend using a Virtual Machine as running it bare is messy. But it's possible.

The problem is that the graphics card is not supported by default. When booting from your usb-stick in the Ubuntu boot menu try the **nomodeset** mode.

[image]

This will boot up with 800x600, basic,  but it works.
For advanced configuration I would recommend you reading through [this article](http://0nit.com/?p=215) as it describes all necessary configuration steps to have a "nice looking" Ubuntu on the Surface 3.